# How can i change value from textbox in row in gridview?

Tags: c#, button, gridview, textbox, aspxgridview

I am getting value from textbox in gridview and trying to change the value with two different buttons. (increase and decrease buttons) First click is working than not working.

I was checking browser's console for getting information and i am getting this information: **"XHR finished loading: POST"** Do you have an idea why button click works only once?

Here is my code for increase:

```
public void btn_increase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(GridViewRow row in gridview1.Rows)
   {
     Textbox quantity = (Textbox)row.FindControl("txt_quantity");
     int input_quantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantity.Text);
     if(input_quantitiy >= 0)
     {
       quantity.Text = Convert.ToString(input_quantity + 1);
     }
   }
}
```

UPDATED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and it's very simple. If your button click is not working and getting  **"XHR finished loading: POST"** error on browser. Check your `Page_Load` and be sure bind gridview in if page is not postback like that:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   gridview.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
   gridview.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have copied that code exactly from your program there are a few issues you could try fixing that might help:

- `input_quantity` in the `if()` statement is spelt incorrectly.
- Swap the `=` and `>` around in the if statement, currently isn't checking for greater than or equal too, but is a `lambda` expression.

Also if you know the ID of the TextBox, and only need to increase/decrease one TextBox, is there any reason to iterate through the GridView? You could achieve the same thing as follow:

```
            TextBox quantity = txt_quantity;
            int input_quantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantity.Text);
            if (input_quantity >= 0)
            {
                quantity.Text = Convert.ToString(input_quantity + 1);
            }
```

Comment: this is my mistake that i just wrote the code not copy/paste. My if statement is like yours. I am not sure why working on only first click after that getting error on browser.

Comment: Are you able to just reference the TextBox out of the loop going through each row in the grid view, or do you have more than one TextBox? The code I included above without the `foreach` loop increases the TextBox correctly.

Comment: This is a gridview ofcourse if you have ten row then you can change value on ten row. Seems working well for once beceuse I can increase/decrease for once. (-1/+1) without any problem. If i set 20 than textbox being 20. I just want every click increase or decrease with my code.

Comment: hey, i found a solution. It's about Page_Load, code is working well. I shared the answer, i hope it's helpful.